# Convert xs:double to xs:integer in xPath 2.0

Tags: xml, xpath, type-conversion, xpath-2.0

I am trying to convert a xs:double to xs:integer in xPath 2.0 with functions (I don't want to use an XSLT).

```
number(//version//number/text())
```

The above output to - 6.0 (taking number as 6.0). How can I convert this to be 6?

Comment: Do you have a text node with a number value? Or do you have an `xs:double` value? And which conversion do you want to perform if there are decimals, do you want to round or truncate?

Comment: I have a text node. I want to truncate the value and convert to integer.

Comment: Then use the xs:integer constructor function (which truncates towards zero). If you want the nearest integer, use `xs:integer(round($x))`.

Comment: Incidentally, double to string conversion in XPath should convert the double 6.0 to "6" rather than "6.0" - it shouldn't be necessary to convert to an integer to change the display format. What XPath engine are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

XPath 2.0 includes constructor functions for built-in XML Schema types, so you could do:

```
xs:integer(number(//version//number/text()))
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#constructor-functions-for-xsd-types. I don't know what your environment is, but this worked without any special namespace configuration in my XML IDE. Your mileage may vary, in which case you'll need to find how to bind the *XML Schema* namespace to the `xs:` prefix in your environment.

By the way, since you are using `//` expressions which could return multiple elements, it may be safer to index `//version` and `//number` with `[1]`, in case you only expect one occurrence: `(//version[1]//number)[1]`.

Comment: `//version[1]` can still return arbitrary many elements. You need `(//version)[1]` to be really sure

Comment: Ah, perhaps where there are multiple version elements under different parents? It would return the first child of each?

Comment: If you have many items, you could get each item converted to number like this: `//version//number/xs:integer(number(text()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `floor` and then construct an `xs:integer`: `xs:integer(floor(//version//number))`.